# Impossible to send input with 2 characters

Tags: php, regex, html, forms

Its weird but when I fill in 2 characters in my form, it doesnt give an error neither it sends.

Here is a snippet of my code.

HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form_name">Name</label>
            <input id="form_name" type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{1,}$"
                   name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name"
                   required="required" data-error="Your name is required">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP code

```
// Check name
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,}+[a-zA-Z[:space:]]{2,}$/", $_POST['name'])) { 
  $errors[] = 'Name'; 
}
```

It has to do something with `preg_match` and/or regex, I tried to remove `{1}` but no result. Also `{1,}` did not work. When I put in **Jo** for example, it doesn't send or give an error. When I put a space after it, it works like a charm.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{1,}` states 1 or more and `[a-zA-Z[:space:]]{2,}` states 2 or more.  So 1 + 2 = 3 so you must have at least 3 characters to match.

Comment: ^^^ Probably this, but your question is very unclear, what does *... neither it sends* mean and where do you even display the error if there is one?

Comment: I think you should remove the white space character `\s` and the regex should work with 2 or more characters

Comment: @AbraCadaver Lol i knew it would be that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Please change the question to answered status :)

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy Then stop vandalizing the post: Don't add links to irrelevant 3rd party sites, don't remove the html5 tag when the OP uses html5 form validation - and the problem is with the validation - and don't try to explain the post when what really is needed is an explanation from the OP.

Comment: Why are you validating a name? Thats a bad idea. Just make sure it has a value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Question is answered by AbraCadaver:

> [a-zA-Z]{1,} states 1 or more and [a-zA-Z[:space:]]{2,} states 2 or
>   more. So 1 + 2 = 3 so you must have at least 3 characters to match.